# zf2: Pass dynamic data to Select in FormCollection

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

i try to work with zf2 form collection.
After uploading an exam i got an array of ExamQuestion objects and i want to provide a form where the user can select the subject for each of these questions.
The available subjects come from the database.

My first problem is, that i don't know how to set the dynamic value_options for the Select elements in the Zend\Form\Element\Collection fieldsets. If you read the following simplified code you will get my idea for a solution:

```
class ExamController {
    public function questionAction() {
        // parse exam ...

        $questions = $parser->getQuestions();
        $subjects = Subject::sorted()->get();

        $form = new ExamQuestionForm($questions, $subjects);
        $this->viewModel->setVariable('form', $form);
        return $this->view();
    }
}



class ExamQuestionForm {
    public function __construct($questions, $subjects) {
        parent::__construct('examquestionform');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name' => 'questions',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Prüfungsfragen',
                'count' => count($questions),
                'should_create_template' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'target_element' => array(
                    'type' => 'Application\Form\QuestionFieldset',
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Speichern',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));

        /*
         * The following code does not work.
         * $collection->getFieldsets() returns an empty array.
         * But the form is rendered if i remove that so the fieldsets must be there?
         */
        $collection = $this->get('questions');
        $questionFieldsets = $collection->getFieldsets();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {
            $questionFieldsets[$i]->setQuestion($questions[$i]);
            $questionFieldsets[$i]->setSubjects($subjects);
        }
    }
}



class QuestionFieldset extends Fieldset {
    public function __construct($name = null) {

        parent::__construct('question');

        /*
         * Here should be a plain text element for the question text.
         */

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => "subject",
            'type' => 'Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Fach',
                'value_options' => array(),
            ),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the fieldset with question data.
     *
     * @param \ExamQuestion $question
     */
    public function setQuestion($question) {
        $this->setLabel('Frage '.$question->number);
        // Here the plain text element from above should be added ...
    }

    /**
     * Adds passed subjects as options in subject select element.
     *
     * @param array $subjects Subject objects.
     */
    public function setSubjects($subjects) {

        $valueOptions = array();
        foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
            $valueOptions[$subject->id] = $subject->name;
        }
        $this->get('subject')->setValueOptions($valueOptions);
    }
}
```

The template is simple:

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form->get('questions'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

This seems not to be the right way to do this. And even it does not work.
Can anyone explain how to handle this task correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got a solution by myself.

Firstly the $collection->getFieldsets() method only works correctly if you call $form->prepare() before. So its not a good way to pass data to your collection fieldsets because prepare() function should be called in the view template.

A possible solution is not to configurate the collection and manipulate its fieldsets afterwards but to create and prepare the fieldsets by yourself in the code and add them to an empty collection. Be aware that each of the fieldsets needs a unique name.